# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_empty'

Tags: python

```
1   l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3]
2   def is_empty(l):
3           """
4           -------------------------------------------------------
5           Determines if the list is empty.
6           Use: b = l.is_empty()
7           -------------------------------------------------------
8           Postconditions:
9               returns
10              True if the list is empty, False otherwise.
11          -------------------------------------------------------
12          """
13  
14          return len(l._values) == 0
15  
16  print("Empty?",l)
17  print(l.is_empty())
```

Trying to check if list is empty, keep getting attribute error and not sure how to fix?

Comment: `is_empty(l)` ..

Comment: You should call the function like this: `is_empty(l)` and not `l.is_empty()`

Comment: by the way, I don't think `List` has an `_values` attribute - and even if it does, that is most likely an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on

Comment: Also python lists don't have any attribute `_values`. Simply use `len(l)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Check out [ask] and [help] as well.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a *function*, not a *method*. That means you have to call

```
is_empty(l)
```

not

```
l.is_empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_empty(inputlist):
    if type(inputlist) == list and len(inputlist) > 0:
        print("<dbg> The list you are checking has a current size of {}".format(len(inputlist)))
        return False
    elif type(inputlist) == list and len(inputlist) == 0:
        print("<dbg> The list is empty!")
        return True
    else:
        print ("<dbg> Error: input must be a list.")


testlist = [1,2,3,4]
emptylist = []
othervar = 123

is_empty(testlist)
is_empty(emptylist)
is_empty(othervar)
```

Output:

```
<dbg> The list you are checking has a current size of 4
<dbg> The list is empty!
<dbg> Error: input must be a list.
```